# Compare two MySQL columns as LIKE %%

Tags: mysql

In my `MySQL` tables I want to select only those rows where the content of the `table2.b3` is in `table1.a3`

```
SELECT table1.a2, table1.a3, table2.b2
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a3 LIKE %table2.b3%;
```

Comment: Perhaps `table1.a3 like concat('%',table2.b3,'%')`

Comment: It is a solution to my problem.
Thank you sgeddes, this was really fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use `FIND_IN_SET` like this:

```
SELECT table1.a2, table1.a3, table2.b2
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.a3
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(table2.b3, table1.a3) > 0;
```